# Div not responding to jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

1. I have a bunch of products that will be loaded(append-ed) to the page when the user loads the page the first time. I use a $.post() call to the database and then append the data as a number of divs into a container.

   ```
    $(function() {

     var profile_looks = $('#profile_looks');

     $.post("apples.php", function(json) {

        var looks = $.parseJSON(json);

        profile_looks.prepend(

        (some code here)

        )

     });  // close $.post()
   ```
2. After these products are loaded, I want the products to change background color on hover.

   ```
     var product_tags = $('.product_tags');

     product_tags.mouseenter(function() {

        $(this).css('background-color', 'white');

     });

     }); // close $(function()
   ```

However step 2 does not work, meaning when I mouseover the product_tags, they do not change. Why aren't the product_tags div responding to the function call?

**Full code below**

```
$(function() {

       var profile_looks = $('#profile_looks');

        $.post("apples.php", function(json) {

               var looks = $.parseJSON(json);

                var page_post = "";

        $.post('oranges.php', function(products_data) {

        var products_display = $.parseJSON(products_data);


        for(i = 0; i < looks.length; i++) {

            var fruits = products_display[i];  

                        for(var key in fruits) {

                         var test = "<div class='product_tags' style='color:" + "black" + "' >" + "<span class='type' style='font-weight:600'>" + key + "</span>" + " " + "<span class='title'>" + fruits[key] + "</span>" + "</div>";

                          var mega = mega + test;


}; // the 2nd for-loop finishes, and re-runs the first for-loop

}; // b=0 timer loop finishes


 profile_looks.prepend(

            "<div class='look'>" + "<div class='look_picture_container'>" +

            "<img src='" + "user_pictures/" + username_cookie + "/" + looks[i][0] + "'>" +

            "<div class='heart'>" +

            "<img src='" + "../function icons/hearticon black.png" + "'>" +

            "<div class='heartcount'>" +


            "</div>" +
            "</div>" +


            "<div class='product_tags_container' style='background-color:" + looks[i][3] +  "' >" + mega + "</div>" +

            "</div>" + // class="look_picture_container"

            "<div class='post_description'>" +
            looks[i][1] +
            "</div>" + // class= "post_description"

            "</div>"); // class="look"

            var mega = "";

        }

        }); // for the $.post(displayproducts.php)
        }) // for the $.post(displaylooks.php)



 var product_tags = $('.product_tags');

    product_tags.mouseenter(function() {

            $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
    });

    product_tags.mouseleave(function() {

    $(this).css('background-color', 'transparent')
    });


}); // end of $(function()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `product_tags` are dynamically generated elements, you need to use `.on` API to delegate the events for such elements. [.on API](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Use this

```
profile_looks.on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'transparent')
    }
}, '.product_tags')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data is arriving asynchronously, while you're creating the "hover rule" (attaching the event handlers) synchronously.

This means that when you write:

```
var product_tags = $('.product_tags');
product_tags.mouseenter(function() {//...
```

`product_tags` is a collection of elements that exist *right after* you dispatch the async POST calls. (The answer to these POSTs didn't arrive yet at this point, so the DOM you want to attach to was not generated either.)

To fix this, trigger the attaching of these `mouseenter` event handlers after the async answer has arrived (from the same callback you're using to work with the returned data), and you've set up the DOM you need to work with.

*Note: the other answers bring up good points about delegating your event handlers via an already existing container using jQuery's `.on()`, which might prove to be a cleaner, more declarative solution.*

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because the elements doesn't exist yet when you try to bind the events to them.

You can use delegated events, which you bind to an existing element where the elements will end up:

```
profile_looks.on('mouseenter', '.product_tags', function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
}).on('mouseleave', '.product_tags', function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', 'transparent')
});
```